# Shift + " (double quotes) button not working in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

`Shift` + `"` button not typing `"` at first press though it works on second or third press, and then it types two doubles quotes instead of just one. It's behaving the same across the system on all applications including the browser, Notepad, VS Code, etc.

Comment: Your description sounds like typical "dead keys" used in international keyboard definitions to support diacritics. What keyboard definition are you using? The solution could simply be to switch to a keyboard definition without dead keys, like US.

Comment: Thanks @StarCat, I already have the keyboard set to `US` layout.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after getting inspired from [another answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49056712/8992678). I found that `Shift` button was used as part of an **Input Language hot key**. And so, it didn't work on the first press but worked on the second press as Windows knew on the second press that I am not going for the shortcut key (hot key). Here's how to disable this behavior:

1. Search for **Advanced keyboard settings**
2. Click **Input language hot keys**
3. Select **Between input languages**, then press **Change Key Sequence**
4. Select **Not assigned** and **Not assigned**, then press the **OK** button
5. Press **OK** again

Now `Shift` button should work as expected. I tested it in Windows 10 version 21H2 (it should work for others too).